# Calculate __half version of FLT_MAX

Tags: cuda

I would like to know the corresponding value of FLT_MAX for the __half data type. For float this is defined in float.h

```
#define FLT_MAX          3.402823466e+38F
```

Is there such definition in any header nvidia provides, and if not, how would I calculate it myself, either programmatically or by hand?